# Delete characters in range of string

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos

I have the following string I would like to edit:

```
var someString = "I wan't this text {something I don't want}"
```

I would like to remove all the text contained in the two braces, no matter how long that text is. I have been using the follow code to remove a section of a String when I know the range:

```
extension String {
    mutating func deleteCharactersInRange(range: NSRange) {
        let mutableSelf = NSMutableString(string: self)
        mutableSelf.deleteCharactersInRange(range)
        self = mutableSelf
    }
}
```

However, I do not know the range in my problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alexander Sorry for the quick and wrong response. Tested with your extension in playground... its working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working with strings and ranges can be quite challenging when mixing `NSString` and `NSRange` with Swift's `String` and `Range`.

Here is a pure Swift solution.

```
var someString = "I wan't this text {something I don't want}"

let rangeOpenCurl = someString.rangeOfString("{")
let rangeCloseCurl = someString.rangeOfString("}")
if let startLocation = rangeOpenCurl?.startIndex,
    let endLocation = rangeCloseCurl?.endIndex {
    someString.replaceRange(startLocation ..< endLocation, with: "")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a RegEx pattern to match anything enclosed with curly brackets:

```
var sourceString: String = "I wan\'t this text {something I don't want}"

let destinationString = sourceString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\{(.*?)\\}", withString: "", options: .RegularExpressionSearch)

print(destinationString)
```

This will print **"I wan't this text "** without the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
extension String {
    func getCurlyBraceRanges() -> [NSRange] {
        var results = [NSRange]()
        var leftCurlyBrace = -1
        for index in 0..<self.characters.count {
            let char = self[self.startIndex.advancedBy(index)]
            if char == Character("{") {
                leftCurlyBrace = index
            } else if char == Character("}") {
                if leftCurlyBrace != -1 {
                    results.append(NSRange(location: leftCurlyBrace, length: index - leftCurlyBrace + 1))
                    leftCurlyBrace = -1
                }
            }

        }
        return results
    }
    mutating func deleteCharactersInRange(range: NSRange) {
        let mutableSelf = NSMutableString(string: self)
        mutableSelf.deleteCharactersInRange(range)
        self = String(mutableSelf)
    }
    mutating func deleteCharactersInRanges(ranges: [NSRange]) {
        var tmpString = self
        for i in (0..<ranges.count).reverse() {
            tmpString.deleteCharactersInRange(ranges[i])
            print(tmpString)
        }
        self = tmpString
    }
}

var testString = "I wan't this text {something I don't want}"

testString.deleteCharactersInRanges(testString.getCurlyBraceRanges())
```

Output: "I wan't this text "